# Too many character in character literal

Tags: c#, asp.net

Any body tell me whats wrong in this code?

```
<span class="color" id="secondColorCode" runat="server" data-color-code="<%# getColorCode((string)Eval('FirstColorCode'),(string)Eval('SecondColorCode'))%>" style="background-color:<%# getColorCode((string)Eval('FirstColorCode'),(string)Eval('SecondColorCode'))%>;"></span>
```

> Error: Too many characters in character literal.

Comment: `'SecondColorCode'` and similar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need double quotes for strings in C#. Single quotes are for characters:

```
Eval("FirstColorCode")
```

Comment: +1 but I think than "<%# this should be changed to this '<%#

Comment: i chang single quote to double quotes but browser render it as it is... sorry for poor english..

Comment: You'll also need to change the quotes at the beginning and end of the attribute as per @ArsenMkrt's comment.

Comment: i tried this but it will generate the following error: The server tag is not well formed

Answer (score 0):

Through out your code you have passed string in single quotes

```
 'FirstColorCode'
```

should be

```
  "FirstColorCode"
```

so your full code will be

```
<span class="color" id="secondColorCode" runat="server" data-color-code='<%# getColorCode((string)Eval("FirstColorCode"),(string)Eval("SecondColorCode"))%>' style='background-color:<%# getColorCode((string)Eval("FirstColorCode"),(string)Eval("SecondColorCode"))%>;'></span>
```

Note i have changed double quotes

```
data-color-code="
```

to

```
data-color-code='
```