# Html.Raw combined with Url.Action asking for syntax help, Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I can't find what I am doing wrong this time.

tried [Too many character in character literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203191/too-many-character-in-character-literal) but seems not to be the case here.
Also worked through the other solutions regarding "too many characters in character literal", maybe I didn't found the right one, if so, I am sorry.

The issue itself explained:

```
var url = @Html.Raw(@Url.Action("Edit", "Home", new {target = "_blank" , Id = @Model.Id}));
```

shows no error in Visual Studio but in Chrome I get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags
```

and the button stays gray and can't be used

```
var url = @Html.Raw('@Url.Action("Edit", "Home", new {target = "_blank" , Id = @Model.Id}))';
```

results in too many characters in character literal

without the @Html.Raw I get &amp: in the url and an error loading the page

Button:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
            .Name("insertButton")
            .Content("Include")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", style = "position:relative;float:right" })
            .Events(ev => ev.Click("onClickInclude")))
```

function:

```
<script>
function onClickInclude() {

    var url = @Html.Raw('@Url.Action("Edit", "Home", new {target = "_blank" , Id = @Model.Id}))';

    window.location.href = url;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = '@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("Edit", "Home", new {target = "_blank" , Id = @Model.Id}))';
```

sometimes it can be so easy. Solution if someone has some issue.